# How do I make one HTML element "stick" to the bottom of another?

Tags: html, css, position

On my website I have two different elements, one being a script that displays who is online my teamspeak server at a given time and the other being a button below that. My issue is that when people join or leave the server, the element that displays the script moves up and down the Y-axis, so sometimes there is a large gap between the button and sometimes the button and the script overlap.

My question is, how do I stick the button to the bottom of the displayed script so that the button moves along the Y-axis with the expanding and contracting script?

Thanks so much for any help. The CSS for the script's positioning is in-line so I pasted it below.

```
<?php if($browser == 'iphone'){ ?><div style="width:350px; height:325px; overflow:hidden; position:static;"><?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the button a child of the displayed script? If so, try adding this to the button:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Alternatively, you could prevent the script from expanding or getting smaller, ensuring that the button stays where it should and the script stays where it should by adding a `max-height` and a `max-width`, coupled with the `overflow: hidden` would theoretically work, although without better understanding how the two elements are in relation to each other, I'm unsure of a proper solution for you.